# How can I format a decimal in xquery?

Tags: xquery, saxon, number-formatting

I'm trying to format decimals in XQuery. The decimals are currency, so the format should be `,###.##`.

For example:

`5573652.23` should be `5,573,652.23`

and

`352769` should be `352,769` (or `352,769.00` if it's easier/cleaner)

Right now I'm using this function from http://www.xqueryhacker.com/2009/09/format-number-in-xquery/, but I can't use decimals with it:

```
declare function local:format-int($i as xs:int) as xs:string
{
  let $input :=
    if ($i lt 0) then fn:substring(fn:string($i), 2)
    else fn:string($i)
  let $rev := fn:reverse(fn:string-to-codepoints(fn:string($input)))
  let $comma := fn:string-to-codepoints(',')

  let $chars :=
    for $c at $i in $rev
    return (
      $c,
      if ($i mod 3 eq 0 and fn:not($i eq count($rev)))
      then $comma else ()
    )

  return fn:concat(
    if ($i lt 0) then '-' else (),
    fn:codepoints-to-string(fn:reverse($chars))
  )
};
```

I'm using Saxon 9HE for my processor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**----- UPDATE -----**

Based on Dimitre's answer, I modified the function to save the decimal portion and add it to the end of the return string.

**New Function**

```
declare function local:format-dec($i as xs:decimal) as xs:string
{
  let $input := tokenize(string(abs($i)),'\.')[1]
  let $dec := substring(tokenize(string($i),'\.')[2],1,2)
  let $rev := reverse(string-to-codepoints(string($input)))
  let $comma := string-to-codepoints(',')

  let $chars :=
    for $c at $i in $rev
    return (
      $c,
      if ($i mod 3 eq 0 and not($i eq count($rev)))
      then $comma else ()
    )

  return concat(if ($i lt 0) then '-' else (),
                codepoints-to-string(reverse($chars)),
                if ($dec != '') then concat('.',$dec) else ()
                )
};
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution :)

Comment: It is not required to use any namespace prefix for the standard XPath functions. If you omit the `"fn:"` prefix, your code will be more readable. Also, at present your coding is inconsistent: why you prefix the `concat()` function, but not the `substring()` function?

Comment: @Dimitre: I don't usually prefix standard functions, but I copied this function from the website noted above. It's inconsistent because I didn't strip out the prefixes when I made the modifications. I'll have to go through and clean it up so it doesn't confuse anyone. Thanks again. Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
let $n := 5573652.23
 return
      concat(local:format-int(xs:int(floor($n))),
             '.',
             substring(string($n - floor($n)), 3)
             )
```

**This produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
5,573,652.23
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dimitre. Based on this answer, I updated the function that I was using. +1 and answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work for you?:

```
format-number(5573652.23,",###.##")
```

You can play with this [here](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#58Inx6kRPaTdNIooBmeMMtglmxQ=). I am pretty sure that saxon supports this function.

**Edit**: This function is not supported in saxon (see comments below).

Comment: No, `format-number()` isn't supported. That was the first thing I tried. I tried changing from HE to PE & EE, but I still get an error: `F [Saxon-EE XQuery 9.3.0.4] System function format-number#2 is not available with this host language`. +1 for a good suggestion though

Comment: Tried `fn:format-number($myelement/*:betrag cast as xs:decimal,"#,##0.00")` in **XQuery 3.0** and with Saxon-HE 9.7 Parser and it works.

Answer (score 0):

With XQuery 3.0 and Saxon-HE 9.7 Parser you can do the following:

```
declare decimal-format local:de decimal-separator = "," grouping-separator = ".";
declare decimal-format local:en decimal-separator = "." grouping-separator = ",";
let $numbers := (1234.567, 789, 1234567.765)
for $i in $numbers
return (
   format-number($i,"#.###,##","local:de"),
   format-number($i,"#,###.##","local:en")
)
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>1.234,57 1,234.57 789,0 789.0 1.234.567,76 
1,234,567.76
```