# XPath in XQuery: Fractional Digits

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

XPath in XQuery:  Fractional Digits

I have an output XSD that looks like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Money">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
       <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

From this I use a statments

```
fn:sum($Accounts/in:IndividualAcct[in:AcctType = 'AttcRec']/in:balance * in:amount)
```

But my summation to a field defined witht the 
definition above appears as:

```
36745.770000000004
```

What I am looking for is only 2 fractional digits

So I am wondering, can I use something like a format-string or fn:string

If so, can I combine this with my previous fn:sum string listed above

What would that look like?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format a decimal in xquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838562/how-can-i-format-a-decimal-in-xquery)

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887784/formatting-the-output-of-the-sum-function-in-xquery-xslt-xpath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify whether you have support for XQuery 3.0. If so, [`fn:format-number($number, $picture)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-format-number) is what you're looking for:

```
format-number(36745.770000000004, '.00')
```

Result: `36745.77`

As @MichaelKay proposed in the comments, an alternative which also works in XQuery 1.0 would be to use the `round-half-to-even($number, $precision)` to limit the precision to two decimal digits. The number will automatically be casted to a string if necessary:

```
round-half-to-even(36745.770000000004, 2)
```

Comment: Can you combine this with the fn:sum command, and what would that look like ?

Comment: You can use arbitrary expressions returning an integer as first parameter. Just put the whole function call in there, something like `format-numer(sum(...), '.00')`. Remember whether to use the `fn:` namespace prefix is a matter of style and debate (usually you can use it for both functions, or omit it).

Comment: Note also, in XQuery 1.0 you could use `round-half-to-even(sum(...), 2)`